# jwksError: Not Found thrown by jwks-rsa module during GET request with auth bearer token to protected api

Tags: api, jwt, auth0, express-jwt

An error - “jwksError: Not Found” is thrown when I make a get request with the correct bearer token in the request header to my protected API. I’ve followed the start up guide to create the *jwtCheck* helper function that I pass to all my routes to protect them. I need help clarifying what this error actually means thanks!

Here I define the helper function *jwtCheck* which will be used to secure all routes.

```
var jwtCheck = jwt({
  secret: jwksClient.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: https://${auth0Domain}/.well-known/jwks.json,
  }),

  algorithms: ['RS256'],
  issuer: https://${auth0Domain}/,
  audience: auth0ApiIdentifier,
});
```

Then I protect my api using jwtCheck defined above like so. After which the api will throw an Unauthorized Error if one tries to send http requests to it without a header in the request with the auth bearer token.

```
const app = express();
...
app.use(jwtCheck);
...
```

I get new Bearer tokens by sending a POST request to auth0apiIdentifier/oauth/token and putting the following in the req body:

```
{
    "client_id":id,
    "client_secret":secret,
    "audience":auth0apiIdentifier,
    "grant_type":"client_credentials"
}
```

After sending the get request via postman with the appropriate bearer token in place, rwks-rsa module throws the subsequent error:

```
JwksError: Not found.
    at ../server/node_modules/jwks-rsa/lib/JwksClient.js:119:23
    at ../server/node_modules/jwks-rsa/lib/wrappers/request.js:36:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

[Img 1 - POST request to get new auth Bearer token from Auth0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go3lh.png)
[Img 2 - GET request sent with postman and corresponding error thrown by jwks-rsa module.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9bCC.png)

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed it! The error was way too ambiguous but after desperation set in, I checked my configs again and I found that I included a "/" at the end of my auth0apiIdentifier, this allowed a "//" in the jwksUri which caused the issue. Solving this typo was my fix.

Check your code guys! Peace!